# Vim Split and VSplit behaviour

Tags: vim, resize, behavior

I love using splits, right now i have a dual monitor setup with different sized screens, i typicality like to have a vertical split on the monitor division which is simple enough.
The problem is when ever i add another vertical split it resizes all vsplits to be the same witdth, as if i "C-w =" then re-sized the horz splits. This same behaviour occurs with horz splits. This makes me need to resize my vertical splits every time i add a new one... 
My question is if it is possible to make the split behaviour bisect the current split only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `equalalways` option for controlling this behavior:

```
:set noequalalways
```

This will cause vim to size each new split *relative the current split*: giving it half the size of the current split, instead of resizing *all* the splits to have the same height.

Note that this is also used for horizontal splits, so if you set this option, you'll get the same behavior when splitting horizontally with e.g. `:vsp`.

Finally, you can also specify a specific size for the next split, by preceding the split command with a value, like: `:17sp`, which will allow the new split *17* lines. This isn't as useful as `noequalalways` because of splits opened other ways, e.g. when using `:help`.

See `:help 'equalalways'` and `:help split` for more information.